# How to change keyformat of existing encrypted dataset

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, encryption

I had an unencrytped dataset that for which I used `zfs send / receive` to create an encrypted dataset with the data. The destination encrypted dataset used key-based creds. I would like to change this to password based auth. Is this possible? Cheers